# How to host WordPress blog in Azure webapp's subfolder?

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, blogs, azure-web-app-service

I want to host a WordPress blog to my existing Azure webapp's sub directory so that user can visit the blog with the url "http://mywebappurl/blog/...". I have tried to follow the steps mentioned [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2013/02/13/hosting-wordpress-in-a-subfolder-of-your-windows-azure-web-site/)

However, now when I visit the url  "http://mywebappurl/blog/", I get "Oops, that page can't be found" error as shown in the image.[image: Page can't be found here]

When I see the error log I get error page as shown in the image:

[image]

From the image I get feeling that some problem is there with the mapping because it is not actually referring to the path ../blog/.. but I'm not aware how to fix this issue.

I can provide more details of Azure web app configuration as needed.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you change the `siteurl` and `home` settings in MySQL ?

Comment: Yes I have changed the siteurl and home to "http://mywebsiteurl/blog"

Comment: is there any `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');` or `define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');` in your `wp-config.php` ?

Comment: I have following details in "wp-config.php" :

$connectstr_dbhost = 'localhost:49870';
$connectstr_dbname = 'localdb';
$connectstr_dbusername = 'azure';
$connectstr_dbpassword = 'password';

define('WP_HOME', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

Do I need to change this?

Comment: these constants override the database settings. you can delete them or set them to the desired value.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: I changed wp-config.php file and set WP_HOME & WP_SITEURL to actual URLs and now it is showing the "Hello World" post so I guess now redirection issue is fixed. Though page is not showing as per the blog's default theme but I guess that would be the different issue. Any other settings to be done in order to fix the theme issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the constants in `wp-config.php` as below:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING). '/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://'. filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING). '/blog');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', '/blog/wp-content');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING). '/blog');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have covered this scenario in my blog post here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/04/19/microsoft-azure-web-sites-deploying-wordpress-to-a-virtual-directory-within-the-azure-web-site/

This is regards to the old portal, but is still relevant with the new one too.